# How to add conditional logic on Chart.js config?

Tags: javascript, html, graph, chart.js

My Chart.js datasets look as following -

```
datasets: [
                
    {   
        data: data_0,
        label: unit_0,
        backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        yAxisID: 'data_0-axis',
    }, 
    
    { 
        data: data_1,
        label: unit_1,
        backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        yAxisID: 'data_1-axis'
    }, 
    
    { 
        data: data_2,
        label: unit_2,
        backgroundColor: "#3cba9f",
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        yAxisID: 'data_2-axis'
    }, 
    { 
        data: data_3,
        label: unit_3,
        backgroundColor: "#000000",
        borderColor: "#000000",
        yAxisID:'data_3-axis'
    }
]
```

I want to add some conditions like checking if data is valid or not. Upon invalid data that data should be poped or not shown on the graph. Basically I want to do something like this -

```
datasets: [
//Some conditions before adding the data to the graph.
    if(condition){            
    {   
        data: data_0,
        label: unit_0,
        backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        yAxisID: 'data_0-axis',
    }}, 
    
     if(condition){{ 
        data: data_1,
        label: unit_1,
        backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        yAxisID: 'data_1-axis'
    }}, 
]
```

It would be helpful if I could get some help on how to achieve something similar to this.

Comment: you can push to the dataset array based on a condition if thats what you wanted

Comment: Did you mean something like graph.data.dataset.push([array])? One of the problems I found when I tried something like this was I am using the Django loop to generate multiple graphs. And when calling the method to generate chart.js and updating the value only applies to the last graph. Can you share some live code snippet?

Comment: a ternary operator maybe https://codeshare.io/78DEj1

Comment: Not exactly the solution I was looking for but got the idea of what I needed to do. Thanks, mate.

Answer (score -1):

From a brief look at Chart.js, it seems that you can use arbitrary JavaScript with it, and **a built-in JS feature that fits this situation perfectly is the built-in [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method** of Arrays.

**This demo code gives a brief rundown of how it can work for you:**

```js
const demo_datasets = [
  {data: "data_1", YAxisID: "data_1-axis"}, // (Has a valid YAxisID)
  {data: "bad_data_1", YAxisID: ""},
  {data: "bad_data_2", YAxisID: 42},
  {data: "bad_data_3" }  
];

// This is how you would populate your actual `datasets` variable. (Initializing 
//   Array w/ spread operator is redundant if demo_datasets is already an Array)
const filtered = filterData([...demo_datasets], hasYAxis);

console.log(`datasets before filtering: ${demo_datasets.length}`);
console.log(`after filtering: ${filtered.length}`)
console.log("\nvalid sets:"); console.log(filtered);


// `filterData` is our main Function
function filterData(dubiousData, filterFunc){
  // `filterData` takes an Array and a Func, uses `.filter` to make a new Array,
  //    which includes only those elements for which Func returns true
  return dubiousData.filter(filterFunc);
}

function hasYAxis(dSet){
  // One possible filter function -- YAxisID must be a non-empty string
  if (dSet.YAxisID && typeof dSet.YAxisID === 'string'){ 
    return true;
  }
}
```